# Android how to access views from my custom list if I use a CustomAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

In my application, I have `ListView` which is set by my CustomAdapter (i.e. ArrayAdapter). CustomAdapter has ViewHolder implemented in it which has references to all the views in my CustomList.
Now my question is how can I access the views in my CustomList (like EditText in below code) as the class hierarchy is like

```
public class BaseActivityClass{
    ...
    class CustomAdapter{
        ...
        public class ViewHolder{
            EditText et;
            ...
            }
        }
    }
```

from my activity BaseActivityClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your `View` a unique id (`View.setId()`) or tag (`View.setTag()`) in your `getView()` method and then use `findViewById()` or `findViewByTag()` to use them

Answer (score 0):

In your Custom adapter

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
View row=inflater.inflate("R.layout.yourcustomlistviewlayout ", parent, false);
EditText et=(EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.youredittext);
}
```

this way you can control your custom adapters views

Comment: What if edittext is not part of the Listview but rather part of the Activity?