# How to set tags in android?

Tags: java, android, textview, findviewbyid

I'm trying to set a tag for a `textView` in android, but I cant seem to figure out how to set the tag, I tried using the following code, and it didn't have any errors but then I cant figure out how to use `findViewByTag` to do something with the textView later, any help would be appreciated!

```
playerCounter.setTag("playercounter"+counter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in findViewByTag() function, are you confusing it with findViewById()?

> Unlike IDs, tags are not used to identify views. Tags are essentially an extra piece of information that can be associated with a view. They are most often used as a convenience to store data related to views in the views themselves rather than by putting them in a separate structure.

From the [Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Tags)

Comment: In many so posts I saw thiks like: > You can give your View a unique id (View.setId()) or tag > (View.setTag()) method and then use findViewById() or findViewByTag() > to use them- [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373951/android-how-to-access-views-from-my-custom-list-if-i-use-a-customadapter) but I can't find any **findViewByTag()** method. So, what are they talking about, I'm really confused.

Comment: @ImranRana The answer in the link you provided is wrong, as you know there is no findViewByTag() method; when in doubt trust the documentation and test it yourself.

Comment: Yeah I tested it, but got confused thinking that it was available in the past after finding occurence of **findViewByTag()** in many places :)